# Как сделать placemarks картинками при подгрузке из json?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Получаю объекты из JSON так:

```
ymaps.ready()
    .done(function (ym) {
        var myMap = new ym.Map('YMapsID', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 1
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

        jQuery.getJSON('items.json', function (json) {

            var geoObjects = ym.geoQuery(json)
                    .addToMap(myMap)
                    .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                        checkZoomRange: true
                    });


        });
    });
```

Формат объекта из JSON:

```
{"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Аптека", }, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}},
```

В итоге все объекты у меня отображаются как точки.

Kак сделать их кастомными картинками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем json'е задан пресет метки: `"options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}`.

Если картинки должны быть разными, то нужно в самом файле указать `iconLayout` и другие параметры иконки, [как в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/?from=SO). Если все метки должны иметь одинаковый пин, то можно определить его для уже загруженных на карту объектов.

Вот так:

```
    var geoObjects = ym.geoQuery(json)
            .setOptions({
              iconLayout: 'default#image',
              iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif',
              iconImageSize: [30, 42],
              iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
             })
            .addToMap(myMap)
            .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
```